# skrill POST status response empty with node express

Tags: node.js, express, skrill

How can I extract the data sent to my post request to my status_url?

After a successful payment (in test and live environment) I successfully get a post request to my status_url I provided but the req.body, req.params, and req.query are all empty...

I'm using node express. PS. They don't specify how the post request is sent in their integration docs.

skrill docs: page 22;
https://www.skrill.com/fileadmin/content/pdf/Skrill_Quick_Checkout_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my body Parser settings were incorrect, I needed ({extended:false}) with the bodyParser urlencoder field.

Comment: can you please share your code with me ? . i also have a urgent need to integrate skrill payment in my app but have no idea how to use it. it would be of great help if i would have a look of how things will go. your help will be much appreciated. Thankyou.